# Regex for words, digits, and hyphens

Tags: regex

could you please help me with the regex for the following url, Astericks refers to different page names
www.abc.com/*pagenames*/thank-you

the page names could be page-name, pageName, page12Name, 12pagename, PageNAME etc basically anything in that astericks location should be acceptable.

Thanks,

Comment: So to clarify, the regex should return the first-level folder name?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code or regex writing service. Make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. When you've done so and run into difficulties, you can post here and explain the problem, include the *relevant portions* of your code or regex (including sample data if needed), and ask a specific question related to the problem. In the case of regexes, it's necessary to post samples both of what should match and *what should not*, along with your effort to write the regex yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `/(?<=\/).+(?=\/)/`.

Breaking this down:

- `(?<=\/)` is a positive look-behind on the (escaped) `/` character
- `.+` matches one or more non-line-break characters
- `(?=\/)` is a positive look-ahead on the (escaped) `/` character

Note that positive look-behinds aren't supported in JavaScript, though if you're using JavaScript, you can just **[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** on the `/` and grab the second result:

```js
console.log("www.abc.com/page-names/thank-you".split(/\//)[1]);
console.log("www.abc.com/page_names/thank-you".split(/\//)[1]);
console.log("www.abc.com/page.names/thank-you".split(/\//)[1]);
console.log("www.abc.com/pageNames/thank-you".split(/\//)[1]);
console.log("www.abc.com/page2names/thank-you".split(/\//)[1]);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Obsidian for your detailed response. I am basically trying to write a regex for multiple cases/scenarios. In all the scenarios domain name and thank you part is always same. Just the middle part (page name) changes.

so I tried writing something like this
www\.abc\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[$-\/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]\/thank-you
but its not I think correct

Comment: Why are you passing the whole URL into the regex itself? That's gong to return `www.abc.com/folder/page-name`, but you only want to return `folder`. Also, your regex is indeed not correct. All you need to use is the one that I specified above, which will return **anything** as a folder name, including all special characters. You can see it working in action at [**https://regex101.com/r/F4c8m3/2/**](https://regex101.com/r/F4c8m3/2/).